# Custom install with ZFS Root for Neon (newer Plasma w/20.04 base), SDDM not starting up

Tags: 12.04, plasma, sddm

So following [these instructions](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html) to install Ubuntu 20.04 onto ZFS Root, I got [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org) installed (neon-desktop virtual package). Everything seems good, except when I boot up there's no GUI login. I found SDDM wasn't enabled, so I enabled it `systemctl enable sddm`. When I do `systemctl status sddm` it now shows it's Active, running, no errors.

```
● sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-03-17 23:42:33 PDT; 19min ago
       Docs: man:sddm(1)
             man:sddm.conf(5)
   Main PID: 2103 (sddm)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 76373)
     Memory: 6.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
             └─2103 /usr/bin/sddm

Mar 17 23:42:33 darklaptop systemd[1]: Started Simple Desktop Display Manager.
Mar 17 23:42:33 darklaptop sddm[2103]: Initializing...
Mar 17 23:42:33 darklaptop sddm[2103]: Starting...
Mar 17 23:42:33 darklaptop sddm[2103]: Logind interface found
```

Yet even after I reboot, nothing shows up as a login interface. When I login, and run `startx`, Plasma DE does startup and run fine, everything seems good.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.  *KDE Neon and Kubuntu do share some support sites, alas this is not one of them*

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/  *you tagged 12.04*

Comment: That's...annoying and not obvious from the front. Ah well.